# Influxdb - iteration through influxdb.resultset.ResultSet with tag field slow

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

i'm wondering about the slowniness getting the data from a resultset with a group by tag field in python (v1.8). So unfortunately I can't use the new possibilities in v2.x .

```
time_predicates = get_time_predicates(from_date, to_date) 
query = ( 
    select count({count_column}) as count 
    f"from {measurement}" 
    f"where {' and '.join(time_predicates)} "
    f"group by country" 
)
```

Now when I iterate through this resultset it's unexpected slow.
I tested different things in terms of list comprehension etc., but always it is surprising slow.

```
data = [] 
for measurement, tags in resultset.keys():     
    for points in resultset.get_points(measurement, tags):         
    data.append([tags['country'], points['count']])
```

Without the group by I can do just what is like a fast fetch_all, but without the tag field information:

```
get_points(measurement)
```

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: Looks like using client.request and parsing the json is the way to go.